# I need an explanation about how to use Grails (with different controllers)

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a little and basical Twitter-like site with Grails.

Here is the main part of my project arborescence (UserCwitter handles users, MessageCwitter handles messages and GroupCwitter handles groups like followers/followings) :

[image]

I'm trying to insert a text field to write a new message in the index (here it's **index_final.gsp**).

So I added this piece of code (in every controller my function to create a new user/message/groupe is called **save()**) :

```
<g:form action="save">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

But I don't know why, the form that appears is the one to create a new user and not a message.
Why and what should I do ?

Thanks for your help. Sorry if this is something really easy or even stupid, I'm really new to Grails.

Comment: which folder is this file in? `g:render template="form"` will look for a _form.gsp template file in the same folder where the calling file is

Comment: Can you explain the benefit of adding "Cwitter" to all of your Grails artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

From render tag documentation, related to template attribute:

> Note that if the value of the template attribute starts with a '/' it
>   will be resolved relative to the views directory. This is useful for
>   sharing templates between views. Without the leading '/' it will be
>   first be resolved relative to the current controller's view directory
>   then, failing that, the top level views directory.

So you should use

```
<g:render template="/messageCwitter/form"/>
```

if you want to render form template that is in messageCwitter folder.